# Changing JSON date format received from API. ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, json

would appreciate any help on this. I am using this [API](https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api) and the data is returned in JSON format. However, the date/time is returned as a value similar to this: `dt: 1645068034`
How can I convert this to a readable format in my react project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this in this site [Cloudhadoop-React-timestamp](https://www.cloudhadoop.com/reactjs-convert-timestamp-date/). Feel free to refer to this for additional information.

The date-time format that you are getting from the API mentioned in your question is in the Unix format.
[image: Screenshot of documentation - Openweather API]

```js
let currentTimestamp = Date.now()
console.log(currentTimestamp); // get current timestamp
let date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit' }).format(currentTimestamp)

console.log(date)
```

Intl.DateTimeFormat allows you to specify exactly which format would you want the Unix date in your application to be converted to.[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)

You can also specify if you want to convert the Unix date to just time or date as well

```js
//Just Date
let currentTimestamp = Date.now()
let date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' }).format(currentTimestamp) // 01/11/2021
console.log(date)
```

```js
//Just Time
let currentTimestamp = Date.now()
let date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit' }).format(currentTimestamp)//9:27:16 PM
console.log(date)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option for you:

```
new Date(1645068034 * 1000)
```